# SNMPD not binding correctly

Tags: snmp, syslog

OS: Debian 5.0.3
SNMPD Version: 5.4.1

I have the following two lines in my snmpd.conf file:

> interface eth0
> agentaddress udp:161

I'm getting the following errors in my syslog:

> Oct  5 18:04:44 webdb003 snmpd[29864]:
>   /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf: line 434: Error:
>   Missing TYPE parameter
>  Oct  5
>   18:04:44 webdb003 snmpd[29864]:
>   net-snmp: 1 error(s) in config
>   file(s)
>  Oct  5 18:04:44 webdb003
>   snmpd[29864]: Error opening specified
>   endpoint "udp:161"
>  Oct  5
>   18:04:44 webdb003 snmpd[29864]: Server
>   Exiting with code 1

The [documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/5/snmpd.examples) here says that thats the correct syntax though. However, if I change it to agentaddress 127.0.0.1:161, I can properly snmpwalk the MIB listing when connecting to localhost. My issue is that I also want it to be able to snmpwalk on the public address too without having to specify a public address because I have to push out this config file to all my servers and I really don't feel like writing a config file for each server just because of the ip address differences.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may want to double check that nothing in /etc/default/snmpd is over-riding your configuration. I think by default, the local loopback address (127.0.0.1) is passed in the SNMPDOPTS directive.

I could be mistaken, I just remember having to change that the last time I installed it for Cacti on a Debian system, but I think that was the prior version.

Answer (score 5):

Try the following:

```
agentaddress 0.0.0.0:161
```

Using the address "0.0.0.0" tells most applications/libraries to bind to all addresses.

Comment: although what you said works, the problem is actually the answer submitted by tinkertim. thanks anyways!

Comment: The suggestion by @tim-post didn't help me but the one by @charles-hooper did.  I now have `agentAddress udp:0.0.0.0:161,udp6:[::1]:161` in `/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf` and my daemon starts.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when attempting to start `snmpd` on a system where IPv6 was disabled.

I fixed the issue by changing the below line in `/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf`:

```
agentAddress udp:161,udp6:[::1]:161
```

To the following:

```
agentAddress udp:161
```